# Prove $\int^{\infty}_0e^{-ax}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\arctan\frac{1}{a}-\frac{a}{2}\ln(a^2+1)$, where $a>0$

Tags: calculus

How do you prove $\int^{\infty}_0e^{-ax}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\arctan\frac{1}{a}-\frac{a}{2}\ln(a^2+1)$, where $a>0$?

I have no idea how to start.

Comment: By $\exp ax$, did you mean $\exp -ax$?

Comment: Yes sorry about that, I'll edit that

Comment: Also, is it possible $a^2+1$ should be $a^{-2}+1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following answer assumes a proposed correction to the problem statement.

Let $f(a):=\int_0^\infty\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\exp -ax dx$ so $$f''(a)=\int_0^\infty (1-\cos x)\exp -ax dx=\frac{1}{a}-\frac{a}{a^2+1}.$$Thus constants $B,\,C$ exist with $$f(a)=-\frac{a}{2}\ln (a^{-2}+1)-\arctan a+Ba+C.$$Since $f(\infty)=0\implies B=0,\,C=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\arctan\frac{1}{a}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan a$, we're done.

Comment: Nice solution, for sure and $\to +1$ !

Comment: Hi, how did you get from the second equation to the third equation? ie, from f''(a) to f(a)? Did you integrate $\frac{1}{a}-\frac{a}{a^2+1}$ twice?

Comment: @YipJungHon Yes. The first integral is easy; the second is a bit trickier, unless you've ever differentiated $a\ln a$ before. However, given that we "know the answer", you can just double-check its second derivative is what we need.

Comment: Okay, is there any particular name for this method? Don't believe I seen it before

Comment: @YipJungHon Physicists call it Feynman's trick. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule